# node.js web application with client side rendering

Tags: node.js, web-applications, express, client-side, server-side

I'm building a web application using node.js, this is my first time working with node. I'm using express framework and I have a question about client side rendering.

All the tutorials that I have found online talk about express and server side rendering. They talk about how you can use jade the express templating engine, to serve rendered templates as reponse to your web application.

My application is going to be client heavy and most of the rendering will be done client side. I want to call server to just get plain JSON response and then render it client side, so server side rendering is not of much use.

In this case, is express a right choice? I really like the way I can write APIS in express but I'm concerned about how to serve my application. If I don't want to use the server side rendering it would mean that I would have to serve static HTML at the first call which seems weird to me.

Comment: What you searching for is maybe [angularjs](http://angularjs.org/). Angularjs provides lots of features for the client side.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [Emberjs](http://emberjs.com/) if you want most of the work done on the client side. But still, you need to send the data to the client so one way is to build your app totally on the client side just by sending a plain html and working your way up there. You can also [precompile jade](https://coderwall.com/p/hlojkw)

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing sounds like you are searching for an javascript MVC(or other) solution.

There are a lot of possibilities. Take the right tools for the right job.
Try the following link to get an nice overview of what is possible.

[Helping you select an MV* framework](http://todomvc.com/)